# Is it possible that the attribute autofocus work on hyperlink elements (<a>)?

Tags: html, hyperlink, autofocus

I need to put the "autofocus" attributes on hyperlink elements like this:

```
<a href="mywebsite.com" autofocus focus="javascript code">my link</a>
```

It seems that "autofocus" works only on input elements.

But the focus event works on hyperlink elements.

Maybe I need to change something on my hyperlink elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_autofocus.asp, the `<a>` tag cannot have an "autofocus" attribute.

However, by using jQuery, it is possible:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("myId").focus();
</script>
```